# AutoHotKey WinGetText not retrieving text

Tags: autohotkey, microsoft-edge

I am learning AutoHotKey and trying to see whether I can use it to automate certain processes that we need to do. It will open a browser window using MS Edge (once I get it working I can code it to handle the other browsers), default to a Home page, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to open up a tab to inspect the page's HTML, then search for `MyTech Support Portal`, then backwards search for `:sptth` (`https:`) so I can extract the URL. I'm unsure if I'm handling multiple browser tabs correctly.

*The home webpage contains a drop-down under "Tech Help", that I would put the cursor on, the drop-down opens up, then I select "MyTech Support Portal". I couldn't figure out how to get AutoHotKey to find the text "Tech Help", move the mouse to "MyTech Support Portal", and click on it. I thought if I can look at the HTML source code using Inspect, then I can execute a find and extract that specific url.*. That is why I'm trying to use WinGetText, so I can extract the "MyTech Support Portal" url.

[image: Drop-Down example]

Here is part of the line that contains the url:    `,\"Url\":\"https://xxxxx365.sharepoint.com/sites/ServiceManagementSVCDesk\",\"Type\":\"Group\",\"Title\":\"MyTECH Support Portal\",`

The problem I'm having is when I execute:

`WebText1 := WinGetText(WebTitle2)`

instead of the Inspect text it returns:

> WebText1=Chrome Legacy Window

On line 15, the MsgBox returns:

```
WebTitle1=GNIE HOME - Home - Work - Microsoft Edge
WebPage1=36604
WebTitle2=view-source:https://xxxxx365.sharepoint.com and 1 more page - work - Microsoft Edge
WebPage2=36604
```

Here is my program code (I am just using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to test my code):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

^!r::
{
    Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe", , , &OutputVarPID
    winWaitActive "ahk_pid" OutputVarPID, , 3
    WebTitle1 := WinGetTitle("A")
    WebPage1 := OutputVarPID

    Send "^u"
    winWaitActive "ahk_pid" OutputVarPID, , 3
    WebTitle2 := WinGetTitle("A")
    WebPage2 := OutputVarPID

    MsgBox "WebTitle1=" WebTitle1 "`nWebPage1=" WebPage1 "`nWebTitle2=" WebTitle2 "`nWebPage2=" WebPage2
/*
    Send "^f"
    SendText "MyTech Support Portal"

    send "^f"
    sendText "https:"
    Send "^+g"
*/
    WebText1 := WinGetText(WebTitle2)
    msgbox "WebText1=" WebText1
    Pos1 := instr(WebText1, "MyTech Support Portal")
    if Pos1 = 0 {
        msgbox "'MyTech Support Portal' was not found"
        exit
    }
    Pos2 := instr(WebText1,":sptth:", , Pos1, -1)
    if Pos2 = 0 {
        msgbox "'https:' was not found"
        exit
    }
    url := SubStr(WebText1, Pos2, (Pos1 - Pos2 + 1))
    msgbox "url=" url

}
```

Comment: To copy the URL of the active browser tab use  the hotkeys `Ctrl+C`  after `Ctrl+L`. See also [Get the URL of the current active browser tab](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=3702).

Comment: It's not the url of the current page I want. I need to find the url inside a drop-down list of multiple urls.

Comment: There's no dropdown mention in the question and that makes the potential solution a lot harder, `WinGetText` is not even remotely close. Please edit the question to include **all** necessary details. I assume the dropdown is 100% in the source code? As HTML could be dynamically modified. An example of how the element looks more or less would be handy.

Comment: I have added more info as requested. Thanks

Comment: If the position of that drop-down menu doesn't change, use the [Click](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Click.htm) command. Otherwise try [PixelSearch](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/PixelSearch.htm) to find its position and click on it.

Comment: @RoyM did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution for you:

1. Open the source like you do now.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select everyting:

```
Send, ^a
```

If it doesn't select, [`Click`](https://documentation.help/AutoHotkey-en/Click.htm) on the middle of the page first to gain focus.

3. Copy to clipboard with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>:

```
Send, ^c
```

4. Use [`Clipboard`](https://documentation.help/AHK_H-2.0/Clipboard.htm) variable to access the full value.
5. Do any sort of matching on that. I'd recommend simple [`RegExMatch`](https://documentation.help/AutoHotKey-Functions/RegExMatch.htm) for the desired URL format instead of the weird reverse thing you're attempting. Capture it with a `()` group. Matching `https` alone isn't a good idea either as I don't think that's the only URL on the page.